# Environment variables within a function

Tags: arrays, r, variables, timezone, environment

I am trying to have consistent results within a function that I am using. However, since an array does not remember timezone info, this is a little harder than I expected.

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "")
> ISOdate(2015,1,1,1,tz='UTC')
[1] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
> c(ISOdate(2015,1,1,1,tz='UTC'))
[1] "2015-01-01 02:00:00 CET"
> tz(c(ISOdate(2015,1,1,1,tz='UTC')))
[1] ""
```

As you can see, the array drops the timezone information. This is annoying since other functions like day() of lubridate change behaviour depending on this timezone information.

Therefore I tried the following experiment:

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "")
> Sys.getenv('TZ')
[1] ""
> x <- function(){
      used_timezone <- Sys.getenv('TZ')
      Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
      return(5)
      Sys.setenv(TZ = used_timezone)
  }
> Sys.getenv('TZ')
[1] ""
> x()
[1] 5
> Sys.getenv('TZ')
[1] "UTC"
```

Turns out, it only works if you reset the timezone before the return statement.

Is there a quick way to set an environment variable only within a function without reading the current one and resetting it just before every return?

Comment: Everything after a `return` statement is not executed. Just invert the order of the lines in the function. Or use `on.exit()`, a function that let you execute an expression just before the exit from a function.

Comment: on.exit() is really useful! Thanks for that. The problem is that I have multiple returns and I don't want to repeat it 10 times with the risk of forgetting it somewhere.

Comment: What you mean `multiple returns`? In R a function can return just one object. If you intend multiple conditions, you can put the `on.exit()` on top of the function and it will be executed regardless of the point in which the function exits.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. An if-else construction where it returns one value if true and another if false. This would make two returns and therefore also two times the Sys.setenv. I think on.exit is a good way to do it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read some introductory R material and the help on the functions you are using.

`ISOdate()` does not use the environment variable 'TZ' to choose time zone:

```
> Sys.getenv('TZ')
[1] ""
> Sys.timezone(location=FALSE)
[1] "BST"
> ISOdate(2015, 1, 1, 1)
[1] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 GMT"
```

`ISOdate()` produces a date-time object with an attribute `tzone`:

```
> attributes(ISOdate(2015,1,1,1))
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] "GMT"
```

I don't recognize the `tz()` function, I don't think it is in `base`.

In R a vector (e.g. `1:3`) is not an array:

```
> is.array(1:3)
[1] FALSE
```

`c()` combines its arguments but (from the help) "is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names". By wrapping `ISOdate()` in `c()` you have removed the time zone information.

If you want a vector of dates then you could either, clumsily use `c()` to create the vector then put the attribute back again:

```
> aDate <- ISOdate(2015,1,1,1, tz="cet")
> aZone <- attr(aDate, "tzone")
> aObj <- c(aDate)
> aObj 
[1] "2015-01-01 GMT"
> attr(aObj, "tzone") <- aZone
> aObj
[1] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

... or better, use `ISOdate()` to produce a vector of date objects directly from vector(s) of arguments:

```
> ISOdate(2015, 1, 1:3, tz='cet')
[1] "2015-01-01 12:00:00 CET" "2015-01-02 12:00:00 CET"
[3] "2015-01-03 12:00:00 CET"
```